# How can I get kubuntu to respect previous window sizes?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, konsole, kwin

Every time I open Konsole, or any number of other programs, its y-size is 100% of my desktop, which is a pain. I have the setting "save size and position on exit" checked, and I tried unchecking it then checking it again. I also tried lots of different ways to exit the program, but every time it still opens really big. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Auto stretch ?**

KDE Forums / Windows auto-resize width : http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=97839

**Window rules**

- Configure settings specifically for a window

System Settings > Window Behavior > Window Rules

**Special Window/Application Settings**

Right click the window border > Advanced > Special Window/Application Settings > Size & Position

Size - Remember

[image]

Comment: Thanks, turns out middle-clicking on the maximize button, as per the first link, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to the broader question of remembering size and position, the accepted answer shows how to do it on a per window basis.

The next question is: how about globally setting it for all windows? This was requested all the way back in 2000 in https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15329 which was closed as WONTFIX in 2012. The KWin developer had this to say:

> I am setting this feature request to WONTFIX as it is not possible to implement such a remember policy with our currently used windowing system. Recognizing a window is a non trivial issue. This might become solvable with Wayland but in general remembering cannot be implemented by a window manager or a windowing system, but has to be requested by the clients.

Comment: 2021 and WONTFIX is obviously still present?! Does the art of programming end at problems that are "a non trivial issue"?!